# The monodromy representation $\pi_1(E)\to Mod(F)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, mapping-class-group

Given a fiber bundle $F\to X\to E$, with $F,E$ are Riemann surfaces. I know the monodromy gives a permutation of the fiber. But how to see we have the monodromy representatio: $\pi_1(E)\to Mod(F)$? Here Mod($F$) is the mapping class group of the fiber.

Update: Now I think by locally trivialization, we can get the monodromy gives a homeomorphism from the fiber to itself. But how do we know it preserves the orientation?

Comment: What's $Mod(F)$?

Comment: @Lukas Kofler mapping class group

Comment: The monodromy is a map $\pi _1(E) \to Mod(F)$ which capture the information of when you travel along a loop in $B$, how does that change the diffeomorphsim of $F$. So your definition is wrong.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee fixed

Comment: You just follow the definition: if $c$ is a loop in $E$ based at some $b\in E$, then the pull-back of the bundle $X\to E$ to $c$ defines an $F$-bundle over $S^1$, which necessarily has the form of the mapping torus of a diffeomorphism $h_c: F\to F$, where $F=F_b$. Next, you observe that homotopying $c$ as a based loop changes $h_c$ via an isotopy, i.e. you obtain a well-defined element of the mapping class group of $F$. This is your monodromy representation $\pi_1(E,b)\to MCG(F)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan what about orientation? I don't see how it's orientation preserving.

Comment: It depends on the definition of the mapping class group: Some definitions do not assume "orientation-preserving". Also, if the bundle $X\to E$ is holomorphic (or symplectic) then the haps $h_c$ are automatically orientation-preserving.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan can you explain your last claim?

Comment: Which claim?.....

Comment: @MoisheKohan holomorphic map makes $h_c$ automatically orientation preserving

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104120/discussion-between-6666-and-moishe-kohan).

Comment: @MoisheKohan  why do you just give a confusing answer then left. I tried to understand your answer but it turns out to be time consuming and useless!

Comment: @6666: Because I have other things to do.

Comment: @MoisheKohan at least you can tell the reference.

Comment: @6666 Check Harris and Morrison 'Moduli of curves' or Hubbard's book. If it is not there, I will write a proof.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't think I can find this in either of the books. Please write a proof.

Comment: OK, maybe next week.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you write a proof?

Comment: @MoisheKohan please don't answer any question of me anymore, liar!

Answer (score -1):

If you define the mapping class group as isotopy classes of *orientation preserving* homeomorphisms, then the bundle needs to be oriented.